# React Data Grid using row drag and drop and Drag Columns to Reorder features togather

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to use [React Data Grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/index.html) in my project and I want to use **row drag and drop** and **Drag Columns to Reorder features** together.

I tried to do this by passing `draggable: true` for ReactDataGrid column property and wrapping the ReactDataGrid and Draggable.Container with DraggableHeader.DraggableContainer.

It makes column header moveable but it does not trigger onHeaderDrop action in DraggableContainer and it gave a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

I change  [example23-row-reordering.js](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/packages/react-data-grid-examples/src/scripts/example23-row-reordering.js) according to the description above.

```js
const ReactDataGrid = require('react-data-grid');
const exampleWrapper = require('../components/exampleWrapper');
const React = require('react');
const {
   Draggable: { Container, RowActionsCell, DropTargetRowContainer },
   Data: { Selectors },
  DraggableHeader: {DraggableContainer}
} = require('react-data-grid-addons');

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const RowRenderer = DropTargetRowContainer(ReactDataGrid.Row);

class Example extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    rowKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = { rowKey: 'id' };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this._columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        name: 'ID',
        draggable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'task',
        name: 'Title',
        draggable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'priority',
        name: 'Priority',
        draggable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'issueType',
        name: 'Issue Type',
        draggable: true
      }
    ];

    this.state = { rows: this.createRows(1000), selectedIds: [1, 2] };
  }

  getRandomDate = (start, end) => {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())).toLocaleDateString();
  };

  createRows = (numberOfRows) => {
    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      rows.push({
        id: i,
        task: 'Task ' + i,
        complete: Math.min(100, Math.round(Math.random() * 110)),
        priority: ['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
        issueType: ['Bug', 'Improvement', 'Epic', 'Story'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
        startDate: this.getRandomDate(new Date(2015, 3, 1), new Date()),
        completeDate: this.getRandomDate(new Date(), new Date(2016, 0, 1))
      });
    }
    return rows;
  };

  rowGetter = (i) => {
    return this.state.rows[i];
  };

  isDraggedRowSelected = (selectedRows, rowDragSource) => {
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length > 0) {
      let key = this.props.rowKey;
      return selectedRows.filter(r => r[key] === rowDragSource.data[key]).length > 0;
    }
    return false;
  };

  reorderRows = (e) => {
    let selectedRows = Selectors.getSelectedRowsByKey({rowKey: this.props.rowKey, selectedKeys: this.state.selectedIds, rows: this.state.rows});
    let draggedRows = this.isDraggedRowSelected(selectedRows, e.rowSource) ? selectedRows : [e.rowSource.data];
    let undraggedRows = this.state.rows.filter(function(r) {
      return draggedRows.indexOf(r) === -1;
    });
    let args = [e.rowTarget.idx, 0].concat(draggedRows);
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(undraggedRows, args);
    this.setState({rows: undraggedRows});
  };

  onRowsSelected = (rows) => {
    this.setState({selectedIds: this.state.selectedIds.concat(rows.map(r => r.row[this.props.rowKey]))});
  };

  onRowsDeselected = (rows) => {
    let rowIds = rows.map(r =>  r.row[this.props.rowKey]);
    this.setState({selectedIds: this.state.selectedIds.filter(i => rowIds.indexOf(i) === -1 )});
  };

  render() {
    return  (
      <DraggableContainer
        onHeaderDrop={()=>{console.log('column dropped');}}
      >
      <Container>
        <ReactDataGrid
          enableCellSelection={true}
          rowActionsCell={RowActionsCell}
          columns={this._columns}
          rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
          rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
          minHeight={500}
          rowRenderer={<RowRenderer onRowDrop={this.reorderRows}/>}
          rowSelection={{
            showCheckbox: true,
            enableShiftSelect: true,
            onRowsSelected: this.onRowsSelected,
            onRowsDeselected: this.onRowsDeselected,
            selectBy: {
              keys: {rowKey: this.props.rowKey, values: this.state.selectedIds}
            }
          }}/>

      </Container>
      </DraggableContainer>);
  }
}

module.exports = exampleWrapper({
  WrappedComponent: Example,
  exampleName: 'Row Reordering',
  exampleDescription: 'This examples demonstrates how single or multiple rows can be dragged to a different positions using components from Draggable React Addons',
  examplePath: './scripts/example23-row-reordering.js'
});
```

I went through their documentation but could not find any place where they say these two features can't use together. But in their examples does not provide any example for this.Any example code for documentation describes how to use these two features together would be greatly appreciated.